# Why doesn't unity dash respect the gnome Main Menu entries?

Tags: unity, 11.04

I'm testing out Natty, and one thing I notice is that the custom commands I put in my old main menu don't appear in dash. I click "Applications" and what I get is different from the list in the "Main Menu" preferences. I'd like to be able to write a custom command and have it launched with Unity Dash, is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this was due to a bug in Unity. When you get the latest version of the package unity-place-applications (version 0.2.40-0ubuntu1) this should work. The package hit the main archive last night and should be available in local mirrors shortly.